# Cannot display correctly Latin accent on web side with Python 2.5 in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, utf-8

Very basic [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) Python concern> I cannot display the correct Latin accent on the web side from my custom TinyWebDB database ([CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file encoded in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)) in Python 2.5 in my [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) `main.py` API:

On web: tag = ball bearing / value = roulement \u00e0 billes => NOK!

On an Android phone : tag = ball bearing / value = roulement à billes => OK!

Note: also, if I introduce any Latin character in the `main.py` file, I get an error message when running it.

What is the solution?

Extract from my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs

class StoredData(db.Model):
    tag = db.StringProperty()
    value = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now=True)


def get_value(self, tag):
    entry = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM StoredData where tag = :1", tag).get()
        if entry:
            value = entry.value
        else:
            value = "No result"
        WritePhoneOrWeb(self, lambda : json.dump(value, self.response.out))

#### Write response to the phone or to the Web depending on fmt
#### Handler is an appengine request handler.  writer is a thunk
#### (i.e. a procedure of no arguments) that does the write when invoked.
def WritePhoneOrWeb(handler, writer):
    if handler.request.get('fmt') == "html":
        WritePhoneOrWebToWeb(handler, writer)
    else:
        handler.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/jsonrequest'
    writer()

#### Write to the Web (without checking fmt)
def WriteToWeb(handler, writer):
    handler.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'
    handler.response.out.write('<html><body>')
    writer()
    WriteWebFooter(handler, writer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added to my code :

```
 value = unicode(value)
 value = value.encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace')
```

and it works perfectly.

Philippe